# Viewing "Layers" of an Imported Model

Tags: mesh, viewlayers

I downloaded a free .obj anatomical model that I imported but I am unable to relate to the different systems of the body.  It just looks like the external mesh, but it is supposed to have veins, muscles, etc.  Those systems are listed on the scene view, but I can't figure out how to view them separately.  I am an osteopath who wants to use this as a model for my youtube videos.

My screenshot:
[image: MySceneCensored]

Comment: Hi. I suspect your question is receiving downvotes for the sensitive nature of the model illustrated. Consider posting a different screenshot that shows nudity.

Comment: What you are seeing in the outliner are just materials applied to the model, there doesn't seem to be any additional geometry for the body systems you are looking for.

Comment: To add on to Duarte's comment, you can view the materials by clicking one of the two rightmost of the 4 little circles at the top right of the viewport - these are your preview modes, and the two on the right (Material and rendered) show materials. I don't know how your project is set up, but you can likely switch between the viewable materials by manipulating the material slots. You can find these slots under the material properties tab (the tab with the same pink checkered globe as you see in the outliner).

Comment: Maybe there is hidden geometry underneath the skin of the model ? If you go into wireframe mode (Z > Wireframe or click the leftmost disc in the topright of the 3D viewport), do you see internal organs ?

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  I viewed it in mesh mode and it looks like it's just the skin.  Being in the health field, it didn't even occur to me that nudity would be a problem in an artist forum, but I'll remember that next time!